# Python Web Scraping: Clicking links one by one on Ajax Site

Tags: python, loops, selenium, hyperlink, screen-scraping

I have a list of search criteria saved in a csv file. I'd like to loop through each search criteria to generate the corresponding search results on a website. For each set of search results generated (which are links), I'd like to click into the link and then grab the data from the new page generated. Unfortunately, I am experiencing problems going into each link. If anyone could please kindly provide some insight, it would be **much appreciated**.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# read list of CAS Numbers to be searched
data = pd.read_csv("NPRI CACs.csv", names=["CAS Number", "Chemical Name"])
data.dropna()
CAS = data["CAS Number"]

# Parameters to be called
url = 'http://www.lifelabs.msdss.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMainMenu.aspx%3ffm%3d0%26tb%3d0'

# Sign into SafeTec
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_class_name("text").click()

# Conduct MSDS Searches on SafeTec
for i in range(10):
    try:
        Ingredient_CAS_Number = browser.find_element_by_id("placeBody_dynField48_txtTextBox")
        Ingredient_CAS_Number.send_keys(CAS[i])
        browser.find_element_by_id("placeBody_linkSearchBottom").click()

        list_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='MSDSDetail']")
        links = []
        for j in range(len(list_links)):
            links.append(list_links[j].get_attribute('href'))

        Product_Name = []
        for link in links:
            browser.get(link)
            product = browser.find_element_by_id("placeBody_dynField1_txtTextBox")
            Product_Name.append(product)
        print(Product_Name)

        browser.get(url)
    except:
        print(CAS[i])
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with the code below. Although, the solution is a little inelegant...

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# read list of CAS Numbers to be searched
data = pd.read_csv("NPRI CACs.csv", names=["CAS Number", "Chemical Name"])
data.dropna()
CAS = data["CAS Number"]

# Parameters to be called
url = 'http://www.lifelabs.msdss.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMainMenu.aspx%3ffm%3d0%26tb%3d0'

# Sign into SafeTec
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_class_name("text").click()

# Conduct MSDS Searches on SafeTec
for i in range(2):

        Ingredient_CAS_Number = browser.find_element_by_id("placeBody_dynField48_txtTextBox")
        Ingredient_CAS_Number.send_keys(CAS[i])
        browser.find_element_by_id("placeBody_linkSearchBottom").click()

        list_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='MSDSDetail']")
        all_results = []
        for j in list_links:
            result = j.text
            all_results.append(result)

        for i in range(len(all_results)):
            browser.find_element_by_link_text(all_results[i]).click()
            browser.back()


        browser.get(url)
```